# How to make an email signature responsive?

Tags: html

How to make an email signature responsive?

I tried the code below, but i don't want to use the table tag. Can anyone help me by providing an alternate solution. Thank you.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 620px) {
table[id="outer"] {
max-width: 600px;
width: 20%;
}

img[id="header"] {
max-width: 600px;
width: 40%;
height: auto;
}
td[class="content"] {
font-size: 18px;
}
}
</style>
<table id="outer" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr><td><img id="header" src="download.png" alt="img"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="content"><span style="color: #914400; font-size: large; font-weight:    bold;">Karuna</span><br /><span style="font-size: medium;">Dev / ABC</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="content" > </td>
<td class="content"><span>Pamplemousses</span><br /><span ><span >T</span>: 57678767<br />     <span>W</span>: ABC.com</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="content" style="border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a href="mailto ?
[w3schools mailto example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto)

Bad way to do it though, Mailbox will end up spammed due to email bots that scrape the web for addresses. better off using php if available.

Comment: Thanks Billy..But this is not what am looking for. I need to make an email signature responsive that is if am reading my email using a mobile phone or tablet the email signature should resize to take the size of the phone or tablet.